# $S_4$ Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product

I am trying to show that $S_4 \cong X \rtimes_{\varphi} S_3$ where $X= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.
I know that the group of automorphism on $X$ are isomorphic to $S_3$. I'm not sure if that is something I can use to here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found a normal subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $X$

Comment: Well yes $X$ is normal in $S_4$

Comment: which $X$ ?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The klein 4 group

Comment: So you have a normal subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $X$. Now can you also find a complementary subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $S_3$?

Comment: Im not sure I follow

Comment: ok but just to be clear there are many subgroups of $S_4$ isomorphic to the klein group, but only one of them is normal

Comment: The alternating group?

Comment: A_4 would be normal as its index is 2.

Comment: $A_4$ is normal but it is not isomorfic to the klein-4 group. In fact there is only one other normal subgroup that isn't the whole group or the identity subgroup. And this is the one we need.

Comment: are you referring to V_4?

Comment: $V_4$ isn't naturally a subgroup of $S_4$, you need to find it as a subgroup explictly (in terms of the elements of $S_4$)

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove this we can show that $S_4$ is an internal semidirect product of two subgroups.

First we must find a subgroup $N$ of $S_4$ that is normal and isomorfic to the klein $4$ group. In order to find it we notice it must only have elements of order $2$ or $1$ but cannot contain transpositions (because if it has one transposition it must have all of them and then it must be the whole group).

We find that the normal subgroup we need is $\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

The next thing we must do is find a subgroup $H$ of $S_4$ that is isomorphic to $S_3$ such that $H\cap N = \{e\}$ and $G=NH$.

In order to do this we consider the most obvious candidate: the permutations that fix $1$, clearly the intersection is trivial because no double cycle can move only $3$ elements. In order to see $S_4=NH$ we use $|H_1 H_2| = |H_1||H_2|/|H_1\cap H_2|$.

Comment: Would it be $H \cap N= {e}$ ?

Comment: yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$